# How to align text within a column?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a 3 column webpage. How do I center the header and paragraph on the middle column? How would I align the text to the right when I enter information in the last column? Appreciate the help, thanks.

Also, how do I align the copy right in the middle of the page to the right?

```css
*{  
    font-family: Melvetica;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

body{
    background-color: #6B6A67;
     }     
#container{
    width: 920px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: auto; /*will center your page*/
    margin-right: auto; /*will center your page*/
    }
    
h1, h2{
   text-align: center;
    }



li{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    }
h4{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    }

/*To style an ID within an ID under it use the parent ID--start with header then call the ID you want to select*/
#container #header{
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ADA9A0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px; /*To add empty space to bottom of the element*/
    }  
#container #navigation{
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #ADA9A0;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #ADA9A0;
    }    
    
#container #content{
    background-color: #D9D5CE;
    min-height: 300px; 
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px; /*To add empty space to bottom of the element*/
    }  
    
#container #content #sidebar1{
    background-color: #ADA9A0;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    }     
#container #content #column1{
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 3px; 
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    }         
#container #content #sidebar2{
    background-color: #ADA9A0;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top:-300px;
    }  
   
#container #footer{
    padding-top: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.CR{
       text-align: left;  
       position: fixed;      
}
.Instructor{
    text-align: right;
    position: fixed right;
    }

/*NAV LINKS - add an "a" to style items under the ID'S*/
#container #navigation a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; /*gets rid of the underlining effect*/
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    }
    

    
/*To add a hover put a:hover*/
#container #navigation a:hover{
    color: red;
    background-color: white;
    }
    
    
#container #content #left {
    font-family: Arial;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />

 <title> My Portfolio </title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="container">
        <div id="header"> 
            <h1> CIS 2336- Internet Applications </h1>
            <h2> DeVoll </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <a href="http://tdevoll16f.heyuhnem.com/index1.html/CIS 2336/My Portfolio/MyPage1.html">Home</a>
            <a href="#">HTML/CSS</a>
            <a href="#">PHP</a>       
        </div>
        <div id="content"> 
        
            <div id="sidebar1">
                <h4> Instuctor: Natalia Fofanova </h4>
                <ul>
                    <li> Lectures </li>
                    <li> Syllabus </li>
                    <li> Helpful Videos </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            <div id="column1">
                <h2> HTML and CSS </h2>
                <p>HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) 
                and CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) are two
                of the core technologies 
                for bulding a website. <p>
                
 <p>HTML provides a structure for the page by using "Hypertext" which refers to the hyperlinks that an HTML page may contain. Also, "Markup language" refers to the way tags are used to define the page layout and elements within the page. </p>
<p>CSS provides the visual layout of web pages. They can be used to define text styles, table sizes, and other aspects of Web pages that previously could only be defined in a page's HTML. CSS helps Web developers create a uniform look across several pages of a Web site. Instead of defining the style of each table and each block of text within a page's HTML, commonly used styles need to be defined only once in a CSS document. </p>
 </p>
            </div>
            
            <div id="sidebar2">
            dddd
            </div>
     
        </div> 
        
        <footer>
            <div id="footer"> 
                <div class="CR"> 
                    <h4> Copyright 2016 </h4>
            </div>
                <div class="Instructor"> 
                    <a href="http://heyuhnem.com/"><h4>Copyright Natalie Fofanova </h4> </a>
            </div>
                
        </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is a pure html/css question and got nothing to do with PHP at all.

Comment: Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/15pz3t6b/

Comment: also has nothing to do with `html5`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply use text-align

Ie: `text-align : right` , `text-align : center`

Answer (score 0):

I added `float: left;` and `width: calc(100% - 400px);` to `#column1` (*400px is total width of sidebars*) And I raised `margin-left` and `margin-right` from `#column1` and `margin-top:-300px;` from `#sidebar2` (*no longer need*)

For copyright text, I added:

```
.Instructor h4 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

---

```css
* {
  font-family: Melvetica;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #6B6A67;
}

#container {
  width: 920px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  /*will center your page*/
  margin-right: auto;
  /*will center your page*/
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

h4 {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}


/*To style an ID within an ID under it use the parent ID--start with header then call the ID you want to select*/

#container #header {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ADA9A0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  /*To add empty space to bottom of the element*/
}

#container #navigation {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #ADA9A0;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ADA9A0;
}

#container #content {
  background-color: #D9D5CE;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  /*To add empty space to bottom of the element*/
}

#container #content #sidebar1 {
  background-color: #ADA9A0;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

#container #content #column1 {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: calc(100% - 400px);
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

#container #content #sidebar2 {
  background-color: #ADA9A0;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

#container #footer {
  padding-top: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.CR {
  text-align: left;
  position: fixed;
}

.Instructor {
  text-align: right;
  position: fixed right;
}

.Instructor h4 {
  text-align: right;
}


/*NAV LINKS - add an "a" to style items under the ID'S*/

#container #navigation a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*gets rid of the underlining effect*/
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}


/*To add a hover put a:hover*/

#container #navigation a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
}

#container #content #left {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />

 <title> My Portfolio </title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="header"> 
   <h1> CIS 2336- Internet Applications </h1>
   <h2> DeVoll </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="navigation">
   <a href="http://tdevoll16f.heyuhnem.com/index1.html/CIS 2336/My Portfolio/MyPage1.html">Home</a>
   <a href="#">HTML/CSS</a>
   <a href="#">PHP</a>       
  </div>
  <div id="content"> 
  
   <div id="sidebar1">
    <h4> Instuctor: Natalia Fofanova </h4>
    <ul>
     <li> Lectures </li>
     <li> Syllabus </li>
     <li> Helpful Videos </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   
   <div id="column1">
    <h2> HTML and CSS </h2>
    <p>HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) 
    and CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) are two
    of the core technologies 
    for bulding a website. <p>
    
 <p>HTML provides a structure for the page by using "Hypertext" which refers to the hyperlinks that an HTML page may contain. Also, "Markup language" refers to the way tags are used to define the page layout and elements within the page. </p>
<p>CSS provides the visual layout of web pages. They can be used to define text styles, table sizes, and other aspects of Web pages that previously could only be defined in a page's HTML. CSS helps Web developers create a uniform look across several pages of a Web site. Instead of defining the style of each table and each block of text within a page's HTML, commonly used styles need to be defined only once in a CSS document. </p>
 </p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="sidebar2">
   dddd
   </div>
  
  </div> 
  
  <footer>
   <div id="footer"> 
    <div class="CR"> 
     <h4> Copyright 2016 </h4>
   </div>
    <div class="Instructor"> 
     <a href="http://heyuhnem.com/"><h4>Copyright Natalie Fofanova </h4> </a>
   </div>
    
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a 3 column layout you have to give each column a width. In your case the left and right columns have 200px each. The middle column 490px. Each column will be floated to the left. Floating an element will have it's parent container collapse. 
[Here is a great tutorial on floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

```
    *{  
    font-family: Melvetica;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

body{background-color: #6B6A67;}     

#container{
            width: 920px;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-left: auto; /*will center your page*/
            margin-right: auto; /*will center your page*/
          }

h1, h2{ text-align: center;}

li{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style: none; /*removes bullets from sidebar1*/
    }

h4{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    }

/*To style an ID within an ID under it use the parent ID--start with header then call the ID you want to select */
 #header{
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ADA9A0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px; /*To add empty space to bottom of the element*/
    background: green;
    }  


 #navigation{
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: pink;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #ADA9A0;
    }    

 #content{
    min-height: 300px; 
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px; /*To add empty space to bottom of the element*/
   }  

 #sidebar1{
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    } 

 #column1{
    background-color: teal;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 3px; 
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 490px;
    float: left;
   }   

 #sidebar2{
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px; 
   }  

 #footer{
    padding-top: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    clear: both;
    background: pink;
    }

.CR{
    text-align: left;  
    position: fixed;      
    }

.Instructor{
    text-align: right;
    position: fixed right;
    }

/*NAV LINKS - add an "a" to style items under the ID'S*/
 #navigation a{
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none; /*gets rid of the underlining effect*/
                padding-top: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 6px;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                }



/*To add a hover put a:hover*/
 #navigation a:hover{
                      color: red;
                      background-color: white;
                      }

#left {font-family: Arial;}
```